# Reprogramming Samsung Earbuds' Buttons

Tags: audio, stock-android, samsung-galaxy-s-6, headphones

I have a pair of Samsung Earbuds which came with my S6 Edge. They have buttons which pause audio and increase or decrease the volume. The buttons only work when it is connected to an android device. Is it possible to reprogram them to move onto the next song or video rather than increase volume? And is this a hardware or software thing?

Comment: At least there are [several apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_headset) to control headset button behavior. Maybe one of them fits yours?

Comment: [Head set button controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kober.headset) is well spoken of.  Or You can automate also

Comment: I don't know if it works with stock rom on Samsung devices, but in CM and LineageOS there's a setting to allow volume keys to switch track by longpressing. Only works when the screen is off, but it works with both wired and bluetooth headsets, as well as with the volume keys on the device.